# How to get all images of a single product using Product Advertising API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

Using the following request I get the primary product image with different sizes but not the image gallery that you see in a product view:

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService
&Operation=ItemLookup
&ResponseGroup=Images
&IdType=ASIN&
&ItemId=B004HO6I4M
&AWSAccessKeyId=[Your_AWSAccessKeyID]
&AssociateTag=[Your_AssociateTag]
&Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]
&Signature=[Request_Signature]
```

Is there a way to get the entire image gallery of a single product?

Answer (score 2):

use

```
ResponseGroup=Images,ItemAttributes,Variations,VariationImages
```

and look for ImageSets tag in the xml

hope it helps

Comment: If there is someone using the **amazon-ecs gem for rails**, here is an example to get all the variation images urls   `@imgs = Amazon::Ecs.item_search('iphone 6',  { :response_group => 'Images',:search_index => 'All' })`  `@imgs.items[1].get_array('ImageSets/ImageSet/LargeImage/URL')`